# Get Llama-2 Rotary Embeddings

Tags: gpt, llama-2, transformers

I want to get the Llama-2 rotary embeddings. I do `print(model)` and get the following output:
[image]

In the picture I highlight the rotary embeddings.

How can get the rotary embeddings and how can I interpret the output? What means 32x LLamaDecoderLayer and in its round brakets are four layer plus LlamaRotaryEmbeddings?

It's possible to get the embeddings as the first hidden-state `hidden_state[0]` and I want to know, which hidden-state represents the rotary embeddings.
Am I right, that there are several rotary embeddings?

Thanks in forward.

Best regards.